# Substituting a subclass instance to a superclass reference c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

```
class MovablePoint : public Point { 
   // MovablePoint is a subclass of Point
   // Something 
}
Point * ptrP1 = new MovablePoint(11, 12, 13, 14);
```

if i got the above format,may i know in this case my pointer `ptrP1` will point to object of type `Point` or to object of type `MovablePoint` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dynamic_cast` for that:

```
MovablePoint* pMovPoint = dynamic_cast<MovablePoint*>(ptrP1);
```

It will return a valid pointer if the conversion is possible, and otherwise will return 0.

Comment: Do you mean in the above example the ptrP1 will point to object of class Point.If i want to make it point to object of class MovablePoint then i will need to do the casting?

Comment: If you have a `Point*` pointer and you want to find out if it really points to a `MovablePoint*` then you can use `dynamic_cast` as shown. If that's not what you were asking you may need to rephrase your question.